# Unexpected results from sum using gekko variable

Tags: gekko

I am optimizing a simple problem where I am summing intermediate variables for a constraint where the sum needs to be lower than a certain budget.

When I print the sum, either using `sum` or `np.sum`, I get the following results:`(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((i429+i430)+i431)+i432)+i433)+i434)+i435)+i436)+i437)+i438)+i439)+i440)+i441)+i442)+i443)+i444)+i445)+i446)+i447)+i448)+i449)+i450)+i451)+i452)+i453)+i454)+i455)+i456)+i457)+i458)`

Here is the command to create the variables and the sum.

```
x = m.Array(m.Var, (len(bounds)),integer=True) 
sums = [m.Intermediate(objective_inverse2(x,y)) for x,y in zip(x,reg_feats)]
```

My understanding of the intermediate variable is a variable which is dynamically calculated based on the value of `x`, which are decision variables.

Here is the summing function for the max budget constraint.

```
m.Equation(np.sum(sums) < max_budget)
```

Solving the problem returns an error saying there are no feasible solution, even through trivial solutions exist. Furthermore, removing this constraint returns a solution which naturally does not violate the max budget constraint.

What am I misunderstanding about the intermediate variable and how to sum them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to diagnose the problem without a complete, minimal problem. Here is an attempt to recreate the problem:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
nb = 5
x = m.Array(m.Var,nb,value=1,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
y = m.Array(m.Var,nb,lb=0)

i = []  # intermediate list
for xi,yi in zip(x,y):
    i.append(m.Intermediate(xi*yi))
m.Maximize(m.sum(i))
m.Equation(m.sum(i)<=100)

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

print(x)
print(y)
```

Instead of creating a list of Intermediates, the summation can also happen with the result of the list comprehension. This way, only one Intermediate value is created.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
nb = 5
x = m.Array(m.Var,nb,value=1,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
y = m.Array(m.Var,nb,lb=0)
sums = m.Intermediate(m.sum([xi*yi for xi,yi in zip(x,y)]))
m.Maximize(sums)
m.Equation(sums<=100)

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

print(sums.value)
print(x)
print(y)
```

In both cases, the optimal solution is:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.560000001336448E-002 sec
 Objective      :   -100.000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
[100.0]
[[1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
[[20.0] [20.0] [20.0] [20.0] [20.0]]
```

Try using the Gekko `m.sum()` function to improve solution efficiency, especially for large problems.